# Problem with xepersian ver 2.8

Tags: xetex, xepersian

when I update `xepersian` package to ver 2.8, and use XeLaTeX compiler for the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper]{book}‎
\usepackage{xepersian}‎
\begin{document}
$m$
\end{document}
```

then I see the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\SetMathCode #1#2#3#4->
  \Umathcode #1="\mathchar@type #2 \csname sym#3\endcsn... l.6 {$m $}
```

is this a package bug? can I fined older version of `xepersian`?

My log file starts

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xelatex 2013.5.24)
```

‎

Comment: We will need more detail: what exactly is the error? Please copy and paste the `.log` output into the question.

Comment: log file is too long, LOG FILE :
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xelatex 2013.5.24) 25 MAY 2013 12:33
entering extended mode ....
**t.tex
("C:\Users\M\Desktop\New folder\t.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar

Comment: Can you paste the bit after "Undefined control sequence"? (The bit that says which control sequence is undefined.)

Comment: @Dadsetani I mean specifically the error message you see.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
\SetMathCode #1#2#3#4->\Umathcode
#1="\mathchar@type #2 \csname sym#3\endcsn...
l.6 {$m
$}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.